# How to change font in wordpress when the style is given in body tag?

Tags: wordpress

I want to change the font-family of my wordpress blog. However, modifying css does not work because the generated HTML is like following:

```
<body style="font-family:'Helvetica', Helvetica, sans-serif" class=...>
```

I think such style has the highest priority, so how to overwrite it?

Answer (score 0):

You can override it by adding `!important`:

```
body {
  font-family: tahoma !important;
}
```

However, I'd look into why your HTML has inline styles at all - using !important often leads to headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to overwrite the !important properties. Make sure if there are !important statements in the file. You cannot overwrite the properties with !important statement.